# Is there a downside to configuring a modem to use a dynamic IP when it has a static IP from the ISP?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip

I'm looking at the setup of a modem and noticed that it's been setup to take a dynamic IP, but actually it has a static IP. Is there any downside to doing this or a reason to change it? The internet connection is currently working fine.

Details:
I think it's a static IP because the address is written on the contract with the provider

```
Dedicated IP: xxxxxx
```

Is there such a thing as a dynamic IP on a 2-year lease?

Comment: There is no reason to change it

Answer (score 3):

How do you know it's taking a static IP? Could just be a dynamic IP with a long lease. Configuring it to a static IP, when your ISP actually uses DHCP, could cause problems later on if the modem ever drops offline and the ISP re-assigns its IP to another device. Setting the modem to a static IP also will keep it from getting other DHCP settings which are best left to your ISP to manage.

Comment: I guess its a static ip becuase my ip address is written on the contract with the provider `Dedicated ip : xxxxxx`, is there such a thing as a dynamic ip on a 2 yr lease (the length of the contract) ?

Comment: @sam Generally DHCP leases expire much sooner than that, but they can be very long. Are you subscribed to a business-class service? Typically, consumer-grade internet connections don't get a dedicated static IP.

Comment: its a business class service

Answer (score 1):

There is/can be a semantic difference between a "Dedicated IP" and a "Static IP", and I think that's partly what's throwing you off here.

A 'static IP' is usually referring to an IP address you hard-set in your client device.

A 'dedicated IP' from the ISP (in this case at least) is going to be a DHCP reservation set on the ISP's side assigned to your router's MAC address. You're router requests an IP via DHCP, but instead of the ISP giving you whatever the next available address is (ie: a 'Dynamic IP'), it sees you have a reservation for a certain IP, so it always gives you (and only you) that address, since it's been reserved for you.

Watch it though (this is where the semantics comes in), because DHCP reservations are sometimes referred to in ways that use the word *static*, such as "Static Allocation":

> This feature is variously called *static DHCP assignment* by DD-WRT, *fixed-address* by the dhcpd documentation, *address reservation* by Netgear, *DHCP reservation* or *static DHCP* by Cisco and Linksys, and *IP address reservation* or *MAC/IP address binding* by various other router manufacturers.

[Blurb Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol#Overview)

The reason they do this is because it gives the ISP the advantage of providing you with an unchanging "static" or "dedicated" IP address but without having to do (or explain) anything different in regards to your end's hardware configuration, then they would for anyone using a dynamic IP.

Aside from initial setup, it's also useful if you decide later that you don't want to pay for the dedicated IP anymore, or you'd like a different dedicated IP then can just remove or change the reservation on their end, and no changes will need to be done to your end.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on the ISP. In many cases, requesting a static IP is an extra charge. But that policy is dependent on the policies for an individual ISP.

For example, when I was using DSL from a local phone provide, my IP address was changed dynamically each time the modem was restarted. But on my personal Mi-Fi unit—that uses 3G cellular data—my IP address is 100% static all the time & I never asked for it.

The only downside to a static IP is everyone will know it’s you coming if they check IP addresses! But past that, that might be a desirable thing & I do not see it as a big deal.